# Inserting count based on string

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename

I am trying to add count based on a string value in a csv file.

I have 4 different types of strings values:

```
cat
dog
mouse
hamster
```

The code below adds count regardless of a string value.

How would I get my code to add count in order e.g. cat1, cat2, dog1, dog2 etc.

I'm using the following code:

```
import os
import csv

count = 0
    
with open('rename.csv') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f)
    for line in lines:
        os.rename(line[0], line[1] + str(count) + '.jpg')
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from collections import Counter

import os
import csv

c = Counter()
with open('rename.csv') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f)
    for line in lines:
        c.update([line[1]])
        os.rename(line[0], line[1] + str(c[line[1]]) + '.jpg')
```